# Integrating Okta SSO in my React Project Using Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, openid-connect, okta

I was using Firebase authentication earlier in my React Native application(developing using Expo), the app is for my university and I want to with to the SSO system that my university uses. I got details like client_id , client secret and issuer url, I have the redirect urls as well.
I was wondering how can I go about integrating the SSO system like a popup on the app, using firebase. The OIDC provider is OKTA.
If there are any project on GitHub regarding this, please comment below.

Thanks!

I dont know how to deal with token IDs and stuff

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.